# preg_match to .NET equivalent

Tags: c#, php, .net, regex

I have the following code in PHP:

```
    if (preg_match('@^[a-z0-9/._-]+$@i', $script)
      && !preg_match('@([.][.])|([.]/)|(//)@', $script))
```

I'm making the assumption that the predicate for the `if` statement returns true for the string `js/core.js`.

How would I translate this to C#? The dumb translation is as follows:

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(script,"@^[a-z0-9/._-]+$@i")
   && !Regex.IsMatch(script,"@([.][.])|([.]/)|(//)@"))
```

but I suspect that the `@` symbol has meaning associated with it that I can't get to the bottom of. A translation to .NET regex would be nice, but I'm entirely familiar with .NET regex, so an explanation of the relevant syntax differences would suffice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@`s are just delimiter. You don't need them in .NET

```
if(Regex.IsMatch(script,"^[a-z0-9/._-]+$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
   && !Regex.IsMatch(script,"([.][.])|([.]/)|(//)"))
```

Comment: Awesome. My PHP-fu is very poor. I simply can't muster the enthusiasm to turn it around. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The @ symbol in .net is syntactic sugar that denotes that the following string will be a literal and is located outside of the quotes. this allows for a string where you do not have to double-escape the backslash character (`\`). So "c:`\\`foo`\\`bar" becomes @"c:\foo\bar"